# Overwrite sheets in Excel with Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python (and programming in general) and am running into a problem when writing data out to sheets in Excel.

I'm reading in an Excel file, performing a sum calculation on specific columns, and then writing the results out to a new workbook. Then at the end, it creates two charts based on the results.

The code works, except every time I run it, it creates new sheets with numbers appended to the end. I really just want it to overwrite the sheet names I provide, instead of creating new ones.

I'm not familiar enough with all the modules to understand all the options that are available. I've researched openpyxl, and pandas, and similar examples to what I'm trying to do either aren't easy to find, or don't seem to work when I try them.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# declare the input file
input_file = 'TestData.xlsx'

# declare the output_file name to be written to
output_file = 'TestData_Output.xlsx'
book = load_workbook(output_file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

# read the source Excel file and calculate sums
excel_file = pd.read_excel(input_file)
num_events_main = excel_file.groupby(['Column1']).sum()
num_events_type = excel_file.groupby(['Column2']).sum()

# create dataframes and write names and sums out to new workbook/sheets
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(num_events_main)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(num_events_type)
df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'TestSheet1')
df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'TestSheet2')

# save and close
writer.save()
writer.close()

# dataframe for the first sheet
df = pd.read_excel(output_file, sheet_name='TestSheet1')
values = df[['Column1', 'Column3']]

# dataframe for the second sheet
df = pd.read_excel(output_file, sheet_name='TestSheet2')
values_2 = df[['Column2', 'Column3']]

# create the graphs
events_graph = values.plot.bar(x = 'Column1', y = 'Column3', rot = 60) # rot = rotation
type_graph = values_2.plot.bar(x = 'Column2', y = 'Column3', rot = 60) # rot = rotation
plt.show()
```

I get the expected results, and the charts work fine. I'd really just like to get the sheets to overwrite with each run.

Comment: What if you don't use `load_workbook`? By my recollection, `pd.ExcelWriter` overwrites and existing workbook when its initialized.

Comment: `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='openpyxl')` already has a book, so there is no reason to use `book = load_workbook(output_file)`

Comment: dubbbdan, thank you! That worked! I appreciate your help.

Comment: posted the answer to your post.  Please accept and upvote (if you think it deserves it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [`pd.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) documentation:

> Multiple sheets may be written to by specifying unique sheet_name.
>   With all data written to the file it is necessary to save the changes.
>   Note that creating an ExcelWriter object with a file name that already
>   exists will result in the contents of the existing file being erased.

Try writing to the book like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[4,5,6]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('g.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'first_df')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'second_df')
writer.save()
```

If you inspect the workbook, you will have two worksheets.

Then lets say you wanted to write new data to the same workbook:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('g.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'new_df')
writer.save()
```

If you inspect the workbook now, you will just have one worksheet named `new_df`

If there are other worksheets in the excel file that you want to keep and just overwrite the desired worksheets, you would need to use `load_workbook`.

Before you wrtie any data, you could delete the sheets you want to write to with:

```
std=book.get_sheet_by_name(<sheee_name>)
book.remove_sheet(std)
```

That will stop the behavior where a number gets appended to the worksheet name once you attempt to write a workbook with a duplicate sheet name.